# Read number from file, increment and write back

Tags: c++, file, casting

I want to read a `long` number from file then increment it and write it back to file. 
I am struggling with the convertion from `string` to `long` and back again.

I tried:

```
double id = atof("12345678901"); //using atof because numbers are too big for atio()
id++;
ostringstream strs;
strs << static_cast<long>((static_cast<double>(threadId)));
string output = strcpy_s(config->m_threadId, 20, strs.str().c_str());
```

But that converts the input to a negative or wrong number.

Comment: Consider using `strtoll` or `strtoull` instead of `atof`.

Comment: Also, what's the type of `threadId`? You probably don't need the cast from it to a double.

Comment: How do you plan on writing back the number? If it increases the amount of numerals everything afterwards in the file will need shifting along. e.g 99 -> 100 needs 3 digits space afterwards, whereas only 2 before.

Comment: @PeterWood: I am writing a the file every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` is for normal integers. There's also `atol` and `atoll` (`_atoi64` in windows):

```
//long long id = atoll( "12345678901" );
long long id = _atoi64("12345678901"); // for Visual Studio 2010
id++;
// write back to file here
```

As suggested by one commenter, use `strtoll` instead of the `ato*` functions:

```
char * data = "12345678901";
long long id = strtoull( data, NULL, 10 );
id++;
```

Since you're using C++ here, you should just pull it straight from the fstreams:

```
long long id;
{  
   std::ifstream in( "numberfile.txt" );
   in >> id;
}
id++;
{
   std::ofstream out( "numberfile.txt" );
   out << id;
}
```

Comment: @PeterWood the std::ifstream and std::ofstream will read and write a long in textual format, not in binary.

Comment: If I read it straight from stream the number `12345678901` in the file will result in `-858993460` in my `long` var. Using `atol` will result in the number `2147483647` which is incorrect either.

Comment: @juergend Using the long-long (as edited) should solve that problem. Depending on how large you expect the numbers to get, you may be out of luck using a single native type, though.

Comment: @Greyson: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and it does not contain a `atoll` which is part of C++11.

Comment: Depending on how large these number are going to be, you may have to abandon using only 64-bit integers, and use a multiple precision library (like mpfr or gmp).

Comment: @Greyson: It works using `long long id = _atoi64("12345678901");`. Could you please add that your your answer?

Answer (score 2):

To go from a C string (`char` array), use this:

```
long id = atol("12345678901");
```

Now you can increment the number. Then, to go from a `long` to a C++ `std::string`, use this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << id;
std::string idAsStr = oss.str();
```

Now you can write the string back to the file.

Comment: Using `atol` will result in the number `2147483647` which is incorrect.

Comment: That depends on your platform. In Mac OS X `atol` returns the correct value, but a `long` is 8 bytes wide on my system. You can check the width of a `long` on your system by simply outputting `sizeof(long)`. If you are getting bad values and/or the byte width is too small, switch to a `long long` and use `atoll` instead.

Comment: `atoll` cannot be found in Visual Studio 2010. :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)? You could simply do the conversion like this:

```
double id = boost::lexical_cast<double>("some string");
++id
std::string id_string = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(id);
```

and use whatever file transfer you currently have.